# PicklingError: Can't pickle <class ...>: it's not the same object as ... in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

I'm getting a PicklingError from this line of code in my GAE Python app:

```
deferred.defer(email_voters_begin, ekey, voter_list)
```

The three arguments are:

- email_voters_begin -- A Python function, eg., function email_voters_begin at 0x1035d4488
- ekey -- A key to an entity I defined, eg., prints as agdvcGF2b3Rlcg4LEghFbGVjdGlvbhgCDA
- voter_list -- A list of objects I defined, eg., [models.Voter object at 0x103d3d310, ... ]

When this line executes as part of my tests (with webtest and nosegae), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/Users/joneill/OpenSTV/OpenSTV/trunk/OpaVote-HR/tasks.py", line 29, in init_voters_and_send_email
    deferred.defer(email_voters_begin, ekey, voter_list)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 249, in defer
    pickled = serialize(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 221, in serialize
    return pickle.dumps(curried, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  [...]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 753, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo'>: it's not the same object as google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo
```

Note that the `Voter` entities passed in `deferred.defer()` do not have a `BlobReference` property, but the `Voter` entities do have a `ReferenceProperty` to another entity that does have a `BlobReference` property.  I wouldn't think that any BlobInfo objects would be part of the pickle but the error suggests one is being included.

This error does not occur when I run the same code from a browser window using the dev server.

I'm stumped as how to debug this and any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely occurring because you've retrieved the `ReferenceProperty` on at least one of the Voter objects. Once you dereference a `ReferenceProperty`, the model instance caches it. Pickling pickles any cached objects too, so it attempts to serialize the `Voter` instance, the referenced instance, and its `BlobInfo`.

In general, as Skirmantas points out, it's usually a bad idea to pass model instances to deferred. Where possible, send keys, and if not, serialize the instances to Protocol Buffers and send those instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass instances of models to a deferred. Use keys instead:

```
deferred.defer(email_voters_begin, ekey, [v.key() for v in voter_list])
```

In your email_voters_begin:

```
def email_voters_begin(ekey, voters_keys):
    voter_list = models.Voter.get(voters_keys)
```